# AJAX post to send email - webmatrix

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to send form data, using serialize, to another page that uses that data to send an email. Instead of sending the data the the process page, it appends the data to a querystring on the form page. I've included the correct URL in the ajax query, so i'm not sure why this is happening?

Here's my code:

```
<form id="idForm">
<div>
    <label>Your name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customerName" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Your email address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customerEmail" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Details about your enquiry:</label>
    <textarea name="customerRequest" cols="45" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="propertyid" value="@rPropertyId">
<button id="submitButtonId" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitButtonId").click(function() {
    var url = "~Email/BookingEnquiry";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); 
       }
     });

return false; 
    });
}:;

</script>
```

I was advised by numerous online forums that i should include the "return flase" element too, could this be the problem?

Comment: Also, i haven't added a method and an action to my form, but i shouldn't need to right, the ajax code should handle all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this one

```
$("#submitButtonId").click(function () {
    var getdata = $('#idForm').serialize();
    $.post('~Email/BookingEnquiry', {setdata:getdata}, function (data) {
        $('#mydata').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: i'm not sure i understand, how will it know what URL to send that data to?

Comment: now you can send the data on this file and the data come back on the #mydata div via html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I deleted my old answer, it seems like you have a syntax error somewhere (I can't find it)

This is how I would have done it, I have not programmed alot, but I think its a OK way of doing it.
Please ask if there is anything I can help with

```
<form id="idForm">
<div>
    <label>Your name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="customerName" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Your email address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="customerEmail" />
</div>

<div>
    <label>Details about your enquiry:</label>
    <textarea id="customerRequest" cols="45" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="propertyid" value="@rPropertyId">
<button id="submitButtonId" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#idForm').submit(function (){ // If the form was submitted
        var customerName = $('#customerName').val(), // All the values from the fields...
            customerEmail = $('#customerEmail').val(), //
            customerRequest = $('#customerRequest').val(), //
            propertyid = $('#propertyid').val(); //
        $.post("PATH/FILENAME.php", // The php-file to process the data
            {
            // In the php-file, use $_POST['customerName']; --> etc
            customerName : customerName, // all the values + their names
            customerEmail : customerEmail,
            customerRequest : customerRequest,
            propertyid : propertyid 
            },
            function(data){ // What to do with the data when finished.
            alert(data); // Data is the same as whats beeing echo'ed in the php-script
        });
    });
});
</script>
```